# DateTime.ToUniversalTime() not correct

Tags: c#, datetime, utc, localtime

I have a problem with the `ToUniversalTime()` method.

A little bit of information first: I live and work in germany, so my standard time zone is UTC+1. But now (in summer) my time zone is UTC+2.

I need to convert my local time to UTC for my application. So I tried at first:

```
OutputTime = InputTime.ToUniversalTime();
```

but that only subtracted 1 hour instead of two. After a little bit of research I discoverd that `InputTime.Kind` was `Unspecified`, so I tried:

```
InputTime= DateTime.SpecifyKind(InputTime, DateTimeKind.Local);
OutputTime = InputTime.ToUniversalTime();
```

but still get the same problem.

And my biggest problem is that if I try this

```
TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now)
```

it gives me a timespan of two hours.

Any ideas please?
Thanks

Comment: We don't know what `InputTime` is, which doesn't help. (If it's for a date which doesn't fall in DST in your time zone, that would explain the problem.) Please provide a [mcve]. I strongly suspect that the problem is with your expectations rather than with `ToUniversalTime` in this case. (Much as I dislike `DateTime`, I don't think this particular call is likely to be broken.)

Comment: Why do you need to convert time?  The time is already stored in computer as UTC.  When inputting time the default is to use local timezone settings of computer.  If you collect data in another timezone then when you input data you must specify timezone.  When the output will be displayed in current timezone.  If you need to output with a different timezone then you can convert.

Comment: Input time is a timestamp in format (yyyyddMMTHHmmss) in it is the value  that my program gets from the user, so it is the same time son as the pc wich is running this programm. 

I nedd to convert the time to UTC because i creat and send an ICS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it's the best solution, but this certainly works:

```
var InputTime = new DateTime(2016, 10, 12, 12, 22, 0, DateTimeKind.Local);
var offset = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now);
var OutputTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(InputTime - offset, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

Comment: Note that this may go wrong if `InputTime` is outside of Daylight saving period (e.g. december) and `DateTime.Now` is inside. So instead of `GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now)` you may simply have to do `GetUtcOffset(InputTime)`.

Comment: I had changed it anyway, but anyway thanks for the hint

Comment: This helpd me out, because if the date falls within a range of time when daylight savings is observed... Timezone.CurrentTimeZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(DateTimeInstance)